# How to handle multiple kinds of errors with condition-case?

Tags: error-handling

With `condition-case`, is there a way to handle multiple kinds of errors?

Currently I have `user-error` and `error` both being handled.

Is there a way to de-duplicate these checks to handle any kind of error?

```lisp
(condition-case err
  (some-code)
  (user-error (message "%s" (error-message-string err)))
  (error (message "%s" (error-message-string err))))
```

Comment: I was under the impression `error` handled any kind of error. I read that "there is one handler ..., error, which covers all errors." from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html#Handling-Errors

Comment: Checked, your right. This could be made into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html#Handling-Errors) `error` handles all kinds of errors. So, adapting your example, this is what you'd do to catch them all.

```
(condition-case err
  (some-code)
  (error (message "%s" (error-message-string err))))
```